# Django how to solve saving empty form problem?

Tags: python, django

I am trying take 2 different forms in one page in my Django project.

They have different form models but they are in the same page and use the same view function.

When I try them both of them works, but when I post one of them, the other one is also saving as a empty form. But I do not want this.

Why this is happening?

**views.py**

```
def ocr(request, id):
    ...
    pdf = get_object_or_404(Pdf, id=id)
    approval = ApprovalProcess(user_id=request.user, highest_rank=1)

    #FORM 1
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PdfRiskForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=pdf)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

            if pdf.risk_rating == "Low Risk":
                n = len([x for x in doa_low_list if x < pdf.credit_limit])
                approval.highest_rank = n
            elif pdf.risk_rating == "Medium Risk":
                n = len([x for x in doa_medium_list if x < pdf.credit_limit])
            ....
            approval.save()

    else:
        form = PdfRiskForm()

    #FORM 2 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_2 = CommentForm(request.POST or None)

        if form_2.is_valid():
            form_2.instance.comment_other = form.cleaned_data.get("comment_other")
            form_2.instance.username = request.user
            form_2.instance.comp_name = userP[0].company
            form_2.instance.doc_id = pdf

            if form_2.comment_others is not None:
                form_2.save()

    else:
        form_2 = CommentForm()
```

**models.py**

```
class PdfRiskForm(forms.ModelForm):
    risk_rating = forms.ChoiceField(label='Risk Rating', choices=Pdf.RISK_RATING)
    credit_limit = forms.IntegerField()
    comments = RichTextField
    letter_portion = forms.IntegerField(min_value=0, max_value=100, required=False, label="Guarantee Portion (%)")

    class Meta:
        model = Pdf
        fields = ['risk_rating', 'credit_limit', 'letter_portion', 'comments']

class CommentFromOthers(models.Model):
    comp_name = models.ForeignKey(CompanyProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    doc_id = models.ForeignKey(Pdf, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True)
    comment_others = RichTextField(blank=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())
    username = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**template.html**

```html
    <div class="card-body">
        <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <!-- Very Important csrf Token -->
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.media }}
            {{ form|crispy }}
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Approve">
        </form>
    </div>

    ...

    <div id="demo" class="collapse">
        <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
           <!-- Very Important csrf Token -->
           {% csrf_token %}
           {{ form_2.media }}
           {{ form_2|crispy }}
           <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Send">
        </form>
     </div>
```

Comment: your form has an issue, it should not return true when the form is invalid.

Comment: In your model `CommentFromOthers` all except the field username has either `null=True` or `blank=True` or a default this means that it is fine if an empty entry is submitted for them. Also you don't seem to be taking the username field from user and set it yourself in the veiw. Meaning your form can be submitted entirely blank and it would be valid....

Comment: Why are you using the same view function for two different forms in the first place?

Comment: are those forms related to one another? if yes, I suggest do link those models to signals.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd be better to handle the forms in different view functions.

If you're bent on handling both forms in the same function, you will need to add a "marker" field that you check before you attempt to validate the form.

```
if request.method == 'POST' and request.POST.get('form') == 'risk': 
    form = PdfRiskForm(...)
elif request.method == 'POST' and request.POST.get('form') == 'comment': 
    form = ...
```

and then submit the `form` field along with the form you're submitting:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="hidden" name="form" value="risk" /> <!-- or comment -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be to send each form to a different URL (each with its own view).

The 2 forms can still be in the same HTML page (same template), but you specify a different [`action` attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp) for each.

```html
        <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"
              action="/my-url-1/">
            ...
        </form>

        ...

        <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"
              action="/my-url-2/">
            ...
        </form>
```

This way you can simplify each view and no unnecessary data (meaning: the other forms data) gets POSTed to the views.